# What is "at+jwt" in the header of my JWT?

Tags: jwt

I've seen the header of a few tokens looking like this.

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}
```

It's not clear to me what the *at* stands for nor what it implies. Checking the [docs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519.html#section-5.1) didn't tell me much. Googling the thing is a bit difficult because the keyword is treated as a preposition. So, not many relevant hits there neither.

Is it something specific to IDS4 (which is the framework we're using to create our tokens)? It's not apparently documented there neither but that's the usual state of things. I wouldn't assume that because I've seen it mentioned in the [context of Spring](https://community.auth0.com/t/spring-security-does-not-accept-at-jwt/52965) but I'm too uncertain to tell.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-bertocci-oauth-access-token-jwt-00.html My guess it simply stands for "authentication token"

Comment: @Jens I've checked the article and it bugs me so much that they never state what the *at* stand for. It could be, as you guess, *authentication token* but it also could be *access token* or *auth type*... I'd feel much more confident if I had a list of possible values of the *typ* field somewhere. This seems so cryptic and random. *Type **must be** 'at+jwt'.* Why? How? Not happy...

Comment: Maybe a better resource: https://www.iana.org/assignments/oauth-parameters/oauth-parameters.xhtml#token-type-hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9068

> This specification registers the "application/at+jwt" media type,
> which can be used to indicate that the content is a JWT access token.
> JWT access tokens MUST include this media type in the "typ" header
> parameter to explicitly declare that the JWT represents an access
> token complying with this profile.  Per the definition of "typ" in
> Section 4.1.9 of [RFC7515], it is RECOMMENDED that the "application/"
> prefix be omitted.  Therefore, the "typ" value used SHOULD be
> "at+jwt".  See the Security Considerations section for details on the
> importance of preventing OpenID Connect ID Tokens (as defined by
> Section 2 of [OpenID.Core]) from being accepted as access tokens by
> resource servers implementing this profile.

See also https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9068#section-4 for how you must validate tokens following this profile.

Comment: It kind of answers my question but leaves me with a sensation of information void. I start to understand that there's no exhaustive and definite list of legal values of `typ`. Still, I'd love to understand more fundamentally what else (reasonably, in practical terms) that my appear as a value of it. Is it common to see e.g. `typ:it+jwt`, where *it* would be *identity token* as derived from *at* being *access token*? It's also a bit unclear to me what the advantage is to explicitly requiring a JWT to declare being access token in its header. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Quoting from https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8725#section-3.11

Use Explicit Typing

Sometimes, one kind of JWT can be confused for another.  If a particular kind of JWT is subject to such confusion, that JWT can include an explicit JWT type value, and the validation rules can specify checking the type.  This mechanism can prevent such confusion.  Explicit JWT typing is accomplished by using the "typ" Header Parameter.

The typ values are regular mime-types with the "application/" part excluded.

Comment: Basically this prevents one JWT that doesn't have mutually exclusive validation rules to be confused and accepted in places where it shouldn't be used.